# Is there any theorem from linear algebra about writing random variables as a linear combination of their elements?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, random-variables

Suppose that $X$ is a random variable which belongs to a standard probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mu)$. Could anybody provide some theorem and its details where $X$ can be written as $X=\sum_{i=1}^kw_ix_i$, where $w_i\neq 0$ and and $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *elements* of random variable $X$.  A random variable is often defined as a real-vaued function, and it makes sense to construct a new random variable as a linear combination of old random variables.

Comment: You want $X=\sum_{i=1}^kw_ix_i$. I assume you mean that $w_i\in\mathbb R$, $x_i\in\mathbb R$. This is then hopeless as the LHS is a vector and the RHS is a number.

Comment: @hardmath ok...this is a conclusion that is based on linear algebra...but could you tell me where to find the exact definition/proposition/theorem/whatever for a random variable?

Comment: @jlammy ok this is a mistake, in how i defined $X$, say that $X$ is a real valued function and ignore how I wrote it. Can you then answer my question? I will change the definition above

Comment: Recall $X$ is a function $\Omega\to\mathbb R$. So if you want to express $X$ as a linear combination $X=\sum\alpha_iY_i$ where the $\alpha_i\in\mathbb R$ then you will need the $Y_i$ to be functions from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ too. Put another way, look at the equation you wrote $X=\sum w_ix_i$. The LHS is a **random** variable, i.e. its value is not deterministic. So something on the RHS has got to be random too.

Comment: @jlammy I understand that now. Thank you. Have you seen any such definition/proposition/theorem/whatever where one random variable can be written as a linear combination of another one?

Comment: @HungerLearn:  Have a look at the [tag info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/random-variables/info) for [tag:random-variables].  There are already a lot of Math.SE Questions with this tag.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, not a fancy theorem, but suppose $X$ is a real-valued random variable with finite support $\{x_1,...,x_k\}$. Then we can write

$$X=\sum_{i=1}^k {\bf 1}_{X=x_i}x_i.$$

Notice the indicator weights are Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: thanks. It's a nice thought...and let us see if anyone else has anything else to tell us

Comment: In fact, for any random variable $X$, we can find random variables $Y_n$ that are (finite) linear combinations of indicator functions s.t. $Y_n\to X$. An explicit construction is e.g. given [here in Theorem 4.6](https://people.math.gatech.edu/~heil/6337/spring11/section4.1.pdf)

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by setting the indicator weights as Bernoulli random variables? Give an example or something?

Comment: @HungerLearn, any indicator random variable is Bernoulli since it only takes values 0 or 1.

Comment: Ok...so you mean that you can write the random variable as the sum of the support since for every element of the support the indicator function takes the value $1$ else it is zero?

Comment: Yea, $1_{A}$ is $1$ if $A$ holds and $0$ otherwise